# Blog Posts break the footer

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to WordPress and I am creating a theme from scratch, because I wanted to look exactly as my design. At first, it was pretty straight forward, having the index.php and calling the header and the footer, even the loop is very easy. But, after struggling to find why isn't working, I have finally find a way to display my posts in the blog page. However, I have a problem. I do not have a pagination because I don't know how to do it, and when I add multiple posts the container goes all over the footer and beyond. How am I gonna do it to "push" or scale the footer? Sorry if my question sounds a little weird, any feedback would be great. Thanks

Comment: It is a CSS problem, or maybe broken markup, but without the relevant code or _a link to your site_ I am not sure how to help.

Comment: Without knowing enough about your code to pinpoint the exact problem, I would also guess it is a CSS problem ... have you floated your content container at all? If so, perhaps you need to add "clear: both;" to your footer's CSS to prevent the footer trying to squeeze up next to the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different questions:

1. How can I create pagnation on my blog page?
2. How can I prevent the content from going beyond the footer/how can I make the content push to footer to the bottom?

**1.** You can create pagnation on your blog page with the following two functions: `previous_posts_link()` and `next_posts_link()` both of these functions have two parameters, with the first parameter you can set the link text.

*Example:*

```
previous_posts_link("&laquo; Previous Posts");
//will output a link:
//<a href="link to previous page">&laquo; Previous Posts</a>
```

**2.** Your second question is a bit harder to answer because you're not providing any code, add your CSS to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

take the pagination from the default themes.

best if you don't have a deep understanding of the WordPress codex to take the default templates and design from them. then you have all the code/functions you might need.